# Checking that an element is zero on maximal ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $R$ be an integral $k$-algebra of finite type, let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module (not necessarily projective ), and let $x\in M$. Assume that $x=0$ in $M/mM$ for all maximal ideals of $R$. Is it true that $x=0$?

This is clearly true if $M$ is projective, but I am interested in the general case. Looking at simple examples (skyscraper sheaves), it seems that the answer should be yes, but I can't find neither a proof nor a counterexample.

I think the assumption implies that $x=0$ in $M/pM$ for all prime ideals of $R$, maybe this is helpful.

Comment: Note that if your comment about prime ideals were true you'd be done because by assumption $(0)$ is a prime ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Let $R = k[x], M = k[x]/x^2$. Then $M/mM$ vanishes identically for all maximal ideals $m = (x - a)$ except when $a = 0$ and when $a = 0$ the element $x \in M$ is sent to zero in $M/mM \cong k$. But $x \neq 0$.

Conceptually what you'd like to do is to argue that $x$ lies in the intersection $\cap mM$ and relate this to the intersection $(\cap m) M$; with the given hypotheses you know that $(\cap m)$ is zero. Unfortunately I think being able to commute an infinite intersection past $M$ like this requires that $M$ is finitely generated projective, as you say.

Comment: @Mindlack: we do have $m \otimes M \cong mM$, but taking tensor products with flat modules only commutes with finite intersections in general. As an explicit counterexample, take $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Q}$; then $\cap p \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}$ where the intersection is over all primes but $(\cap p) \mathbb{Q} = 0$.

Comment: Right, thank you for the reminder (I was sure flatness allowed one to use arbitrary intersection...)

Comment: Thank you. So to conclude that $x$ is zero I would need, for example, $x=0$ after base change to all artinian rings supported at closed points?

Comment: Do we have $(\cap m)M=\cap (mM)$ for finite intersections without flatness?

Comment: @J.P.: 1) That sounds like a promising guess but I don't know how to either prove or disprove it off the top of my head. 2) I'm not sure either way. It doesn't follow formally without flatness but I also can't think of a counterexample off the top of my head.